# Odd downvoting patterns

Tags: discussion, down-votes

well there's some maniac who is downvoting my post, don't he/she owe an explanation to me

[Query to toggle boolean value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912946/query-to-toggle-boolean-value-in-mysql)

[JSON object repeats in PHP output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912812/json-object-repeats-in-php-output/4912848#4912848)

Comment: I think your question is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665002/is-there-a-way-in-mysql-to-reverse-a-boolean-field-with-one-query.

Comment: @belisarius i agree but people usually give comment, i wasn't commented and i was just downvoted 2 times (with no reason) and again downvoted with no comment

Comment: @Shadow Wizard no I don't have any problem, I had been out for a while

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two downvotes are not the end of the world, and no, they don't owe you an explanation. If it is not obvious why the question or answer is bad, it is nice to explain the downvote, but it is not required.

If somebody is serial downvoting you the downvotes will be remove automatically, but 2 downvotes are probably not enough to trigger this.

Answer (score 3):

Have to agree that there were some *very* odd voting patterns going on in the [JSON object repeats in PHP output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912812/json-object-repeats-in-php-output) question - there were effectively three identical answers out of four and all but one of the four were downvoted without explanation.

Somewhat curious.

Comment: It looks a bit like tactical downvoting from one of the answerers.

Comment: @Fabian Pretty much what I presumed - I'd dearly love to know why people waste their time in such a facile manner. :-)

Comment: thanks for you support middaparka... :) though 2 downvote won't make much difference

Comment: @explorex No problems - such things just happen from time to time. Best to just shrug it off and move on. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't require.... orange box appears for member with less than 2000 reputation every time but nothing is forcing the member to add comment.

This is free community so I guess such things can't be avoided without harming the "core" of the community.

Know it's easy to say but it's not a big deal... that person can cast one downvote every time removing 2 rep points, while it cost him 1 point - not pleasant but IMO not the end of the world. :)

Comment: yes you are right, i can accept downvote but not by the same person for no reason

Comment: @exp hard to believe it's something personal.. can you post list of all your downvoted posts please?

Comment: no that two were the only post downvoted, (first answer was downvoted 2 times again vote as toggled) and same happened with the another question. I was annoyed if someone strongly disliked me on SO

Comment: and now someone upvoted my new question, though it is duplicate of another question .... i am sorry, i couldn't find it's solution

Comment: @exp your downvoted question is duplicate to some other question, there are already 2 pending Close votes - I guess the first one to vote for closing also downvoted it because he think you didn't search for existing question first.

Comment: @explorex To be honest, if its only happened twice I'd forget about it and move on. (If some idiot wants to waste their time in such a manner that's up to them.)

Comment: @shadow wizard no it was downvoted the moment i posted (within a minute) and close vote (and again downvote was removed)was later on please see the comment on the last guess it was by alex (with the same question)